# LWC: Is it possible to store part of the schema string to import in Custom Metadata

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

I want to store the fields that need to be imported from the schema in my LWC in Custom Metadata.

So for instance I want to make the following line dynamic:

`import MY_OBJECT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/MyObject__c.Id';`

Where `MyObject__c.Id` is something that gets pulled from Custom Metadata. So I end up with something like:

`import MY_OBJECT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/' + myCustomMtdValue;`

However that line is outside of the class definition and I don't think that it's possible to reference a value that comes from a `@wire` method outside of the class. Are there any other options to make this dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import statements are always static. This is because they are compiled into the component so everything is delivered in a single file. This is also what allows the compiler to complain about typos in the import strings for field and object names. As such, using import statements for this purpose is not possible. You can dynamically load object data with [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info), which is what you'd want to do if you need dynamic field or object information.